# Study of stable oscillations of an inverted pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods

A rigid rod of length L, supported at one end by a frictionless hinge,
connected to an electric motor, through which rapid vibrations are forced
hinge in the vertical direction:

$$S = A\sin(\omega t)$$

Applying Newton's second law gives the equation of motion:

$$\theta'' = \frac{3}{2L} (g - A \omega^2 \sin(\omega t))\sin(\theta)$$

I need to consider the following options and interpret them physically:

[Options table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41uvO.png)

The values P, Q, R are given. For the first two options, the duration of the process T=1.8 sec. For other options T=0.5 sec.

So, I have no idea how to solve this differential equation at all. Also, I should solve it using Runge–Kutta–Fehlberg method. It seems like I should use reduction of a high-order differential equation to system of equations of the first order, but I don't sure.

Comment: RKF is a method with an embedded error estimator used to adapt the step size. The kind of step-size control will influence the result, even if only in digits that do not contribute to the desired accuracy (classical for this method is using a factor 2, more modern is to compute the optimal step size via the 4th root). So how exactly is RKF specified and what error tolerance is given?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I'm using RKF45. Error tolerance - $10^{-8}$

Comment: I meant to express that to most people RKF 4(5) is a Butcher tableau. There is a step size controller that was proposed with the original method, but the same tableau has been used with different step size controllers. Thus the question. // Yes, to apply any standard solver you need to transform into a first-order system. There are often several such systems that can be justified as not-so-arbitrary, in mechanical systems one can use velocity or impulse, in other equations not using the derivatives array may preserver some structure keeping the system compact.